# Query error LIMIT 0,25

Tags: php, sql

This query gives the error LIMIT 0,25 and i don't know why how do i fix this?

```
SELECT btigebruikers.voornaam, btigebruikers.achternaam 
FROM btigebruikers, friendrequest 
WHERE btigebruikers.email = friendrequest.user1 OR btigebruikers.email = friendrequest.user2  AND btigebruikers.email  NOT 'vermesenjonas@hotmail.com' AND friendrequest.status = 1;
```

[Database btigebruikers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrVQj.png)

[Database friendrequest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrEll.png)

Comment: I can not see any *LIMIT* in your query?

Comment: *NOT* must be `<>` (unequals)

Comment: Allso you have to add brackets arround the `OR` operands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
 btigebruikers.voornaam, 
 btigebruikers.achternaam 
FROM 
 btigebruikers, friendrequest 
WHERE 
 (btigebruikers.email = friendrequest.user1 OR btigebruikers.email=friendrequest.user2)
 AND
 (btigebruikers.email  <> 'vermesenjonas@hotmail.com')
 AND
 friendrequest.status = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks! this helped